# Run test cases of particular module in multi module project using maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

1. A multi module maven project.

   Project ABC
     -- Module A
     -- Module B
     -- Module C
2. Module B has Module A dependency.
3. Want to run test cases of only Module B. But build all modules.

Note :I need a mvn command which builds dependent module A first(no test case of this module should run).. then run test case of module B only.. mvn command from parent..

Update ::

I tried this command

```
mvn test -am -DfailIfNoTests=false -pl B
```

Problem is its running module A test cases also. but i don't want to run module A test case. I want only module B test case to be running.

Answer (score 4):

Build and execute a specific test from a specific sub module:

```
mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=test-class-name -pl submodule
```

As your submodule depends on other submodule you need `-DfailIfNoTests=false`

Comment: And `-am` to get Module A built.

Comment: Thanks for reply... But i need a mvn command which builds dependent module A first(no test case of this module should run).. then run test case of module B only.

Comment: i tried this command "mvn test -am -DfailIfNoTests=false -pl B".. problem is its running module A test cases also. but i don't want to run module A test case. I want only module B test case.

Comment: hello @VinaySJain, have you found a solution for your task? as i am having same problem now..